# Friendly ID not working as expected for models Show. Any ways around this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

**Issue:** I have installed the friendly_id gem, it is working how it supposed to for my Users table, but for my Listings model, the friendly URL to use a :name instead of :id isn't working.

Here's my Listings controller in a nutshell:

```
    def show
        @order = @listing.orders.new()
#as you can see, I have no need for a find because i noticed i didn't need it for the show page to show up correctly - idk
    end

    private

    def set_listing
          @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Tried using `Listing.friendly.find(params[:id])` in the set listing as well, and in the `def show`.

What's confusing to me is that I don't even need something like `@listing=Listing.find(params[:id])`

I tried using this in the show: `@listing=Listing.friendly.find(params[:id]`

but it didn't make a difference. I also tried changing the "set_listing" method to include the friendly snippet but that didn't help either - just a shot even though it shouldn't work.

I included this in the model - just like i did for my Users table:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

For example, I have my listing, id: 1, name: Listing Test 1, slug: listing-test-1

I go to domain.com/listings/listing-test-1 and I get

Couldn't find Listing with 'id'=listing-test-1

I did everything the same as I did with the Users table but it doesn't seem to work.

**Question:** Is the fact that I don't call the @listing in the show the issue? If so, is there other ways around this?
 It is important that I call the name instead of the ID

Comment: 1. Restart the server, 2. Open `rails c` and see if you can get this item with `Listing.friendly.find('listing-test-1')`

Comment: Do you have `set_listing` in a `before_action` ?

Comment: @KrzysztofWitczak yes, i did that and it does work that way.

Comment: @MikeHeft Yes, I tried removing that as well and then i get an error about the `@order = @listing.orders.new()` line

Comment: I noticed after the migration is creates a friednly_id schema.  Nothing is being inputted into this schema, is it supposed to?

Comment: The only way I have it working is to do `@listing = Listing.find_by(name: params[:name])` in the show...but with that, whats the point of friendly_id ? Not sure what the issue is here.   any inputs?

Comment: It also works with: `@listing = Listing.friendly.find(params[:name])` but then nothing is validated through the `:id` which sort of defeats using friendly id

Comment: Any follow up on this? What could possibly be interfering with this working? error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Listing with 'id'=listing-test-1):`